# Resizing the root partition using free space

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

I have Ubuntu installed on my Acer laptop. I want to resize the root partition and I already have a large free space, but it's to the left of the root partition.

My question is: how could I use some of that space to extend the root filesystem?

Here you can see the partition layout:

[image: partition layout]

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: The screenshot seems different than what you describe – it shows empty space to the *left* of a large partition... and the large partition doesn't look anything like Ubuntu root (it says NTFS). Are you sure it's actually on the correct disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps involved:

1. ** Backup your Data! ** Modifying partitions can lead to catastrophic data loss, this step is the most important!
2. Boot your machine from a live USB. You cannot work on a partition if it is currently in use.
3. Move all of your partitions to the left with e.g. gparted. This can take a long time.
4. Resize the extended partition (partition 4) in which your Ubuntu partition resides.
5. Resize your root partition (partition 5).
6. Reboot